# Integers in cosine

Tags: code-golf, math, integer, trigonometry

### Integers in cosine

From trigonometry we know that

\$\sin(a) =-\cos(a + \frac{(4*m + 1)\pi}{2})\$

where \$a\$ is an angle and \$m\in\mathbb{Z}\$ (integer).

#### The task

For an input of a positive integer \$n\$ calculate the value of the integer \$k\$ with \$n\$ digits that minimizes the difference between \$\sin(a)\$ and \$-\cos(a + k)\$. Or in a simpler way, generate the sequence [A308879](http://oeis.org/A308879).

#### First few values

1 digit : 8
2 digits: 33
3 digits: 699
4 digits: 9929
5 digits: 51819
6 digits: 573204

#### Output

You can create a function or print the result on the standard output.
Your program needs to be able to calculate at least the 6 cases in the section above.

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code in bytes wins.

#### Reference

https://www.iquilezles.org/blog/?p=4760

Comment: This is [A308879](http://oeis.org/A308879). You know, it's fairly obvious.

Comment: I tried searching for it and didn't find anything, thanks for finding me this :)

Comment: Can the C code in OEIS really compute the answer for 12 digit

Answer (score 11):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 25 bytes

This uses a trick: Mathematica doesn't expand `Sin[51819]` into a proper number even when `Max` is called on a list of such things, and because of how `Last` works, it doesn't care that `Sin[51819]` is not a list and simply returns `51819`.

```
Last@Max@Sin@Range[10^#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE7872Yb898nsbjEwTexwiE4M88hKDEvPTXa0CBOOVbtf0BRZl6Jg1u0YSwXjGmEYBojmCYIpmnsfwA)

Comment: [-1](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE7872Yb819ZzcHBN7HCITgzzyEoMS89NdrQIE45Vu1/QFFmXomDW7RhLBeMaYRgGiOYJgimaex/AA) replacing `Last@` with `#&@@`.

Answer (score 9):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 37 bytes

```ruby
->n{(1..10**n).max_by{|k|Math.sin k}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYu9DoIwGAB3n@IDB35SGwqKdKgLcXBQE@KGxJREAiEWYiGRlD57RZe7W@49lpOp2N1sDkK5BGMS@L7w8It/HuWk5nY@86HGshHQam04MMgTBFGEIKYUAaXhwh1JyE/7KAy2xYpgOTx7N/ZAwSxm6MdBgi2Wd62ERtD@q2NVLgq9lHO6ONBU0FmMY1k31aDTa5Yd05tlgzZf)

Minimising the difference between \$\sin(a)\$ and \$-\cos(a+k)\$ amounts to minimising \$|k-(4m+1)\pi/2|\$ for some \$m\$, or equivalently maximising \$\sin(k)\$.

Iterating over `(1..10**n)` works at least for \$n\le6\$, as required. More generally, according to the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A308879) (reference courtesy of [@Λ̸̸'s 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204614/92901)):

> It is not guaranteed that each term in the sequence produces a better approximation than the previous one,  although numerical evidence suggests so.

Iterating over `(10**~-n...10**n)` is guaranteed to work for any \$n\$, at a cost of 7 extra bytes.

Comment: This seems to work for n <= 8 for me.

Comment: @mypronounismonicareinstate Hence why I said '*at least* for \$n\le6\$'... admittedly I was too lazy to keep checking beyond that. Thanks for improving the upper bound :)

Comment: Nice work, and +1. I think it would break for an `n` where the answer for `n+1` is `10**n` though (due to the inclusive range) - no idea if such an `n` exists, but I imagine it does.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Yes, you're right. One of the 7 extra bytes in the last sentence of my answer is taken up by switching to an exclusive range.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

Port of Dingus's answer. (It's [A308879](http://oeis.org/A308879). From that page, it says that the sequence is also "the n-digit integer m that maximizes sin(m)"...)

```
°LΣÅ½}θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0Aafc4sPtx7aW3tux///xgA)

### Explanation

```
°       10 ** n
 L      1 range
  Σ     Sort by:
   Å½}  Sine
      θ Maximum under that mapping
```

Comment: Nice approach with the sort-by with last item! :) An alternative could have been this 7-byter: [`°LÅ½Zk>`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0Aafw62H9kZl2/3/bwwA), with an implicit map for the Sine builtin; maximum without popping; and getting the index+1 of this maximum in the list. Too bad 05AB1E doesn't use 1-based indexing in this case. ;p

Comment: Including `10**n` could be problematic (as well as inluding numbers less than `10**(n-1)` - as noted on the OEIS page).

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://cran.r-project.org/) <s>30</s> 27 bytes

Following the same thread as [@Dingus' Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204611/85958), as indicated in [the entry to A308879](http://oeis.org/A308879), i.e. looking at the maximum value of \$\sin(k)\$ over \$1,\ldots,10^n\$:

```
which.max(sin(1:10^scan()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/vzwjMzlDLzexQqM4M0/D0MrQIK44OTFPQ1NT87/5fy4uAA)

Comment: an alternative (which comes out to the same length, I think) is to use `which.max`.

Comment: @JDL: thanks. This was my first guess (see TIO) but it adds one byte. I am wondering why `which.max(sin(1:10^scan()))` alone does not work...

Comment: it does work for me (though with `scan` you need to enter an empty line after the n)

Comment: Yes thank you, I just realised I had left the `f=` header in my tio code! I thus corrected my answer.

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, 91 bytes

```java
n->{double r=0,m=0,s,k=Math.pow(10,n);for(;k-->1;)if((s=Math.sin(k))>m){m=s;r=k;}return r;}
```

Port of [*@Dingus*' Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204611/52210), so make sure to upvote him!

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##LU@7bsMwDNzzFUQmCX7AXqvKf5AsGYsOqh8pI4syJDlFYfjbXbrxwAPIO/KOD/M0xaOzWzuaGOFikJYTAFLqw2DaHq57C9D5@WvsoRXMAEnFw/XEEJNJ2MIVCPRGRbMcwqCr3HHF3OqLSd/l5H9EXeW8OvgglC2KplYSByHiSxCRhJWycXJxOqqgrVpDn@ZAENS6qd1t4tvsdpg@PXbgOLG4pYB0//gEI19xd489KepaAb7XFWOWyX8O4PYbU@9KP6dy4sU0ksDs/AbnTIye7pJK/lMeT67bHw) (It's barely able to reach up to \$n=9\$ on TIO before it times out.)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{                           // Method with integer parameter and double return-type
  double r=0,                  //  Result-double, starting at 0
         m=0,                  //  Maximum `m`, starting at 0
         s,                    //  Integer `s` for the Sine calculation, uninitialized
  k=Math.pow(10,n);for(;k-->1; //  Loop `k` in the range (10^input, 1]:
    if((s=Math.sin(k))         //   Set `s` to the Sine of `k`
       >m){                    //   If this `s` is larger than the current maximum `m`:
      m=s;                     //    Replace the maximum with this `s`
      r=k;}                    //    And replace the result with `k`
  return r;}                   //  Return the result after the loop
```

Comment: @JonathanAllan I am? (Although I must admit it's coincidentally to be completely honest.) It currently loops in the range `(10^n, 1]` (exclusive on the left; inclusive on the right) or as notation that's inclusive on both side: `[10^n-1, 1]`. Dunno if the same applies to the other answers though, since I'm not too familiar with those other languages. To clarify: it starts `k` at \$10^n\$, but in the loop-check it uses `k-->1` (check if \$k>1\$, and decrease it by 1 right after that with `k--`. So in the body of the very first iteration, `k` will be \$10^n-1\$.

Comment: Oh, so you are, my bad!

Answer (score 3):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>64</s> 63 bytes

```javascript
n=>[...Array(t=10**n)].map(_=>[9-Math.sin(--t),t]).sort()[0][1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DclRCsIwDADQq/iZbGvYvkRqBQ/gCUqRMleNbM1og@Dpq@/3veMn1rnwribLY2nJtewunoiupcQvqJvGrssYaIs73P91MreoL6qcwRjFQQNSlaKAfgx@Cs0mKcBusnw@2r5nnCVXWRda5Qk8HBIwYvsB)

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ApU õ ñ!sM
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWg&code=QXBVIPUg8SFzTQ&input=Mw)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 9 bytes

```apl
⊃⍒1○⍳10*⎕
```

-7 bytes from [ngn and Adám.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55300296#55300296)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qKO94P@jruZHvZMMH03vftS72dBA61HfVJDEfwUwKOAy5IKxjOAsYzjLBM4yhbPMAA)

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), <s>20</s> 16 bytes

```apl
{i[⊃⍒1○i←⍳10*⍵]}
```

-4 bytes from [Bubbler.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55299238#55299238)

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/vzoz@lFX86PeSYaPpndnPmqb8Kh3s6GB1qPerbG1/9PA/D6wgjWPerccWm/8qG3io76pwUHOQDLEwzP4f5qCIVeaghEQGwOxCRCbArEZFwA)

Implements [Dingus's algorithm.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204611/80214)

### Explanation

```apl
{i[⊃⍒1○i←⍳10*⍵]}
{              } function body
 i     i←⍳10*⍵   assign to i the range of 1 to 10^n
     1○          find the sine of each value in i
     ⊃⍒          Grade(sort) by descending value, select index of first(maximum) value
 i[           ]  return k in i where sin k is maximum
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), <sup><s>53</s></sup> 51 bytes

```
read*,n
print*,maxloc([(sin(1d0*k),k=1,10**n)])
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKilKzNNNT4Mw/v8vSk1M0dLJ4yooyswr0dLJTazIyU/WiNYozszTMEwx0MrW1Mm2NdQxNNDSytOM1eRKzUv5/98MAA)

Port of my own [Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204611/92901). Because why not?

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 51 bytes

```python
import math
lambda n:max(range(10**n),key=math.sin)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcpBCoAgEAXQdZ1ilk5IFC2CoMNMlCXlV8xFnt4IeusXcjo8hlKsCz4mcpKO2syXuGUVwuTkUVGwb6rvmgaszy3PX2pvCy7GRwJZ0H/0yFNdhWiRFLRRYC4v)

Uses [Dingus's observation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/204611/20260) about maximizing sine.